# How declare return of Promise of array of any objects

Tags: typescript, promise

I try to define return from the method that would return Promise of an array of objects:

```
public readAll( ) : Promise<any[]> {

  this.handler.getObject( {
    Bucket              : this.bucket,
    Key                 : this.tableName + '.json',
    ResponseContentType : 'text/plain'
  } )
  .promise( )
  .then( file => { 

    const data : any[] = this._parseData( file.Body.toString( ) ); 

    return new Promise( ( resolve ) => data );
  } )
  .catch( error => {

    return this.writeAll( );
  } );
}
```

however, I am facing error "[ts] A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not returning a `Promise<any[]>` from the function `readAll`. put `return this.handler.getObject(...`

Comment: Add `return new Promise(_ => _);` at the end of your method, cause not all code return a value.

Comment: Adding return new Promise(_ => _); solve problem - THANK YOU

Comment: You want `return data` instead of `return new Promise( ( resolve ) => data );`, and also a `return` before your promise chain.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As the error says, your function readAll expects a return of type **`Promise<any[]>`** Try returning the Promise inside the **`readAll`**

```
public readAll() : Promise < any[] > {
  return this.handler.getObject({
    Bucket: this.bucket,
    Key: this.tableName + '.json',
    ResponseContentType: 'text/plain'
  })
    .promise()
    .then(file => {
      const data: any[] = this._parseData(file.Body.toString());
      return data;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      return this.writeAll();
    });

}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote but the answer is not clear enough, and the code is truncated.

Comment: i posted a wrong code on edit, this was the initial answer i posted:) sorry for the confusion

Comment: After Bergi antipatern comment - your suggestions are WAY TO GO

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion from Andrii Nikolaienko lead to a working solution:

```
protected readAll( ) : Promise<any[ ]> {

  return new Promise( resolve => {

    this.handler.getObject( {
      Bucket              : this.bucket,
      Key                 : this.tableName + '.json',
      ResponseContentType : 'text/plain'
    } )
    .promise( )
    .then( file => { 

      const data : any[] = this._parseData( file.Body.toString( ) ); 
      resolve( data );
    } )
    .catch( error => {

      resolve( this.writeAll( [ ] ) );
    } )
  } );
}
```

Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)!

Comment: Thank you for antipattern warning - after refactoring I go achieved better code what looks exactly like Sajeetharan answer